# Can IDP Initiated implementation be a SAML 2.0 compliant technique?

Tags: .net, single-sign-on, saml

I am newbie trying to learn SAML SSO. I heard that IDP initiated SSO implementation is not a SAML 2.0 compliant standard. Only SP initiated SSO implementation is a SAML 2.0 Compliant. Please let me know if this true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. IDP-Init is part of the SAML 2.0 Web SSO Profiles. You can find it documented in Sect 4.1.5 SAML 2.0 Profiles Doc -- 'Unsolicited Responses". I believe Unsolicited Responses are tested as part of SAML 2.0 Conformance events that most major Federation vendors have attended in the past.

Comment: Thank you for confirming and redirecting me to that document. This clarifies my doubt.